# Get "git log --tags" of temporarily added remote

Tags: git

I have this repo which is basically a list of other repos. What I want to do is to run a script that loops over a list of urls and fetch information about the date of their last release (tag).

```
<for each url in my list>
git remote remove tmp
git remote add tmp https://url-to-another-repo.git
git fetch tmp master
git log tmp/master --tags="*" --max-count=1 --pretty="Last updated %ar"
<next url>
```

That works kinda ok but not the way I want. I am having trouble in getting `git log` to only fetch tags. Instead it also fetches the last commits.

When I clone the same repo

```
git clone https://url-to-another-repo.git
git log --tags="*" --max-count=1 --pretty="Last updated %ar"
```

It shows the right result - that is: only the last **tagged** commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--tags="*"` does not do what you think : it does as if you listed all tags on the command line ; so :

```
git log --tags="*"
# is roughly equivalent to
git log last-stable my/tag v1.0.1 v1.0.2  # whatever tags you have on your repo

git log --tags="*" tmp/master
# is roughly equivalent to
git log tmp/master last-stable my/tag v1.0.1 v1.0.2
```

- in the first case : the first commit (the one you will get by adding the `-1` option) will always be tagged, but you won't know if that tag is part of current branch,
- in the second case, if `tmp/master` is the commit that comes on top, it won't be tagged, and if a tag happened to be ahead of `tmp/master`, again, you wouldn't know if that tag is part of the `tmp/master` branch.

---

1. Using `git log`, you may try to combine `--simplify-by-decoration` with `--decorate-refs=<pattern>` :

```
git log --decorate-refs="refs/tags" --simplify-by-decoration

# you can also filter tags using patterns :
# will list tags "v1.0.1" and "v2.0.3", but not "testing"
git log --decorate-refs="refs/tags/v*" --simplify-by-decoration
```

If you have tags on forked branches, `--simplify-by-decoration` will also keep the merge commits in the list of commits ; if you are looking for tags only on the "main" branch, add `--first-parent` :

```
git log --first-parent --decorate-refs="refs/tags" --simplify-by-decoration
```

2. Another option is `git describe` :

```
# this will give you "the last tag on the branch" (for some definition of "last tag")
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 tmp/master

# you can combine it with 'git log' :
git log -1 $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 tmp/master)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks alot. The option 2 was the one I used. Nice to not having to resorting to cloning the whole repo.

Answer (score 0):

LeGEC answer was what solved my problem and should be the correct answer.

This was my final code.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Outputs a markdown table of the repos and their status listed in a csv list (;) with format
#
# Name1;url1;branch1;Description1;
# Name2;url2;branch2;Description2;

FunctionProcessRepo () {
    git remote remove tmp
    git remote add tmp $2
    git fetch tmp $3
    local last_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 tmp/$3)
    local tag_flag="%S"  # use pretty-format %s (commit header) if no tags
    
    # If no tag found, use last commit
    if [ -z "$last_tag" ]
    then
        local tag_flag="%s"
        local last_tag="tmp/$3"
    fi

    # Fetch info
    local last_update=$(git log -1 $last_tag --pretty="format:%as")
    local last_update_relative=$(git log -1 $last_tag --pretty="format:%ar")
    local release_name=$(git log -1 $last_tag --pretty="format:$tag_flag")

    # Write to table
    echo "| [$1]($2) | $4 | $3 | $release_name | $last_update |" >> $file_output
}

file_input="repo-list.txt"
file_output="repo-table.md"

# Table header in markdown format
echo "| Name | Description | Branch | Last release/commit | Date |" > $file_output
echo "| ------- | ----------- | ------- | ----------- | ----------- |" >> $file_output

# Read from repo-list.txt
while IFS=";" read -r repo_name repo_url repo_branch repo_description end_of_line
do
    FunctionProcessRepo "$repo_name" $repo_url $repo_branch "$repo_description"
done < $file_input
```

it outputs a table like this:

| Name | Description | Branch | Last release/commit | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Repo 1](https://url1) | A repo with no tags | master | Updated Readme.md | 2021-01-13 |
| [Repo 2](https://url2) | A repo with tags | master | ver1.1 | 2021-02-16 |
| [Repo 3](https://url3) | A repo with tags | master | R2020.1 | 2021-02-16 |